# Linear programming and network flow

Tags: algorithms, graphs, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, network-flow

I would like some hint in this homework question. I have to write the max-flow problem (with souce $s$ and sink $t$) as a linear program. I have to do this by defining variables on each $s - t$ path, which is different than the typical approach of considering as variables the flow of each edge.

So far, I thought on the following. Let $f_i$ be the flow of each $s-t$ path, then the objective would be $\max_{f_i} \sum_i f_i$, subject to every $f_i$ is less or equal that the capacity of each edge on that path, plus the flow convservation constraints on each vertex. Is this correct?

Comment: Here is the first hit for the search "max flow linear program": http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/toolkit13/lecture14.pdf.